# Querying a list of geometry objects from Oracle based on list of x and y coordinates

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry

We are using an Oracle database table with `SDO_GEOMETRY` objects. I would like to return the rows where the column with the geometry object contains a certain `point` (x, y coordinate).

I know I can query the table using a single point geometry like this:

```
[..]
WHERE SDO_CONTAINS(D.D_SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(
      2001,
      NULL,
      SDO_POINT_TYPE(<myXCoordinate>, <myYCoordinate>, NULL),
      NULL,
      NULL)) = 'TRUE'
```

But let's say I have a `list` of coordinates and I would like to have all geometry objects/rows where the object contains at least one coordinate from the list. How can I do so?

I know I could for example just implement an `OR` and do something like that:

```
WHERE SDO_CONTAINS(D.D_SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(
        2001,
        NULL,
        SDO_POINT_TYPE(<myXCoordinate1>, <myYCoordinate1>, NULL),
        NULL,
        NULL)) = 'TRUE'
   OR SDO_CONTAINS(D.D_SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY(
        2001,
        NULL,
        SDO_POINT_TYPE(<myXCoordinate2>, <myYCoordinate2>, NULL),
        NULL,
        NULL)) = 'TRUE'
```

but that doesn't seem to scale well when having a list with e.g. 1000 coordinates, right?

Also I might have a temporary table with x and y coordinates and would like to use a join. Not sure how I would do that here?

Comment: How about join on containment condition? What is the type of your "list of points", where does it come from? Because if it is some collection type it should be treated in specific way. Also please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: I could actually think of two use cases. The first one is that it is coming from another table, where x and y are columns with float values. The other use case is using SQL and I thought about something like the IN statement where you just pass a list with values, e.g. X_COORD IN ('x-coord-1','x-coord-2' and so on). But I'm quite flexible here... I would just like to avoid having to do 100x OR statements with SDO_CONTAINS when I have 100 coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just join your "list" of points with the table of shapes using `SDO_CONTAINS` function.

If this list comes from some other table, you can apply join as it is (or by constructing `SDO_GEOMETRY` of type point in place). If you need to pass them "manually", then there's no option because I do not know handy rowset generation functions in Oracle (like `select ... from values ...` in other DBMSes). Some excercises may be done with, for example JSON, or you may use collection type as a source of records, which can be "typed in" manually or passed from outside.

> ```
> insert into poly
> /*Growing squares centered in (0,0)*/
> select 
>   level
>   , sdo_geometry(
>     2003
>     , null, null
>     , SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 3)
>     , SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-level, -level, level, level)
>   )
> from dual
> connect by level < 6
> ```

> ```
> insert into point
> /*List of points (0, y)*/
> select
>   level
>   , 0
>   , level
> from dual
> connect by level < 8
> ```

> ```
> select
>   p.*
>   , pl.id as contained_in
>   , pl.poly.get_wkt() as contained_in_wkt
> from point p
>   left join poly pl
>     /*You may construct point on-the-fly from its coordinates*/
>     on SDO_CONTAINS(pl.poly, sdo_geometry(
>       2001
>       , null
>       , sdo_point_type(p.x, p.y, null)
>       , null
>       , null
>     )) = 'TRUE'
> where 1 = 1
> order by
>   p.id
>   , pl.id
> ```
>
> ```
> ID |  X |  Y | CONTAINED_IN | CONTAINED_IN_WKT                                             
> -: | -: | -: | -----------: | :------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 |  0 |  1 |            2 | POLYGON ((-2.0 -2.0, 2.0 -2.0, 2.0 2.0, -2.0 2.0, -2.0 -2.0))
>  1 |  0 |  1 |            3 | POLYGON ((-3.0 -3.0, 3.0 -3.0, 3.0 3.0, -3.0 3.0, -3.0 -3.0))
>  1 |  0 |  1 |            4 | POLYGON ((-4.0 -4.0, 4.0 -4.0, 4.0 4.0, -4.0 4.0, -4.0 -4.0))
>  1 |  0 |  1 |            5 | POLYGON ((-5.0 -5.0, 5.0 -5.0, 5.0 5.0, -5.0 5.0, -5.0 -5.0))
>  2 |  0 |  2 |            3 | POLYGON ((-3.0 -3.0, 3.0 -3.0, 3.0 3.0, -3.0 3.0, -3.0 -3.0))
>  2 |  0 |  2 |            4 | POLYGON ((-4.0 -4.0, 4.0 -4.0, 4.0 4.0, -4.0 4.0, -4.0 -4.0))
>  2 |  0 |  2 |            5 | POLYGON ((-5.0 -5.0, 5.0 -5.0, 5.0 5.0, -5.0 5.0, -5.0 -5.0))
>  3 |  0 |  3 |            4 | POLYGON ((-4.0 -4.0, 4.0 -4.0, 4.0 4.0, -4.0 4.0, -4.0 -4.0))
>  3 |  0 |  3 |            5 | POLYGON ((-5.0 -5.0, 5.0 -5.0, 5.0 5.0, -5.0 5.0, -5.0 -5.0))
>  4 |  0 |  4 |            5 | POLYGON ((-5.0 -5.0, 5.0 -5.0, 5.0 5.0, -5.0 5.0, -5.0 -5.0))
>  5 |  0 |  5 |         null | null                                                         
>  6 |  0 |  6 |         null | null                                                         
>  7 |  0 |  7 |         null | null
> ```

And below is collection type example.

> ```
> /*Object type to access instances as a single field*/
> create type ts_sdo as object (
>   shape sdo_geometry
> )
> ```

> ```
> /*Table of SDO_GEOMETRY*/
> create type tt_sdo as varray (1048576) of ts_sdo
> ```

> ```
> select
>   p.shape.get_wkt() as point_wkt
>   , pl.id as contained_in
>   , pl.poly.get_wkt() as contained_in_wkt
> from table(
>   /*Then we construct collection from list of points*/
>   tt_sdo(
>     /*Each member is constructed from SDO_GEOMETRY*/
>     ts_sdo(sdo_geometry('POINT(0 1)'))
>     , ts_sdo(sdo_geometry(
>       2001
>       , null
>       , sdo_point_type(0, 10, 0)
>       , null
>       , null
>     ))
>   )) p
>   left join poly pl
>     on SDO_CONTAINS(pl.poly, p.shape) = 'TRUE'
> where 1 = 1
> order by
>   pl.id
> ```
>
> ```
> POINT_WKT        | CONTAINED_IN | CONTAINED_IN_WKT                                             
> :--------------- | -----------: | :------------------------------------------------------------
> POINT (0.0 1.0)  |            2 | POLYGON ((-2.0 -2.0, 2.0 -2.0, 2.0 2.0, -2.0 2.0, -2.0 -2.0))
> POINT (0.0 1.0)  |            3 | POLYGON ((-3.0 -3.0, 3.0 -3.0, 3.0 3.0, -3.0 3.0, -3.0 -3.0))
> POINT (0.0 1.0)  |            4 | POLYGON ((-4.0 -4.0, 4.0 -4.0, 4.0 4.0, -4.0 4.0, -4.0 -4.0))
> POINT (0.0 1.0)  |            5 | POLYGON ((-5.0 -5.0, 5.0 -5.0, 5.0 5.0, -5.0 5.0, -5.0 -5.0))
> POINT (0.0 10.0) |         null | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b91489f5a78e3908f30b27321f49113c)*

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I tried your solution and that works totally fine for me!